# primes congruent to 5 mod 6 and 1 mod p

Tags: prime-numbers

I believe that for every prime $p\geq 5$ there exists at least one prime $q$ that is both congruent to 1 mod $p$ and congruent to 5 mod 6. It's well known that there are an infinite number of primes congruent to 1 mod $p$ and there are an infinite number of primes congruent to 5 mod 6, but the conjunction of the two conditions is baffling me. Any ideas? (The conjecture is true for $p < 437,077$ because programming).

Comment: $q\equiv  1\!\mp 2p\pmod{6p}$  for $\, p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{6},\,$ see $ $ [Sophie Germain primes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime)

Comment: Thanks, I did look at Sophie Germain primes briefly, but no ideas came to mind.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, you will find that 
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} x&\equiv &5\pmod{6}\\ x&\equiv &1\pmod{p}\end{array}\right.$$
Has a unique solution $\pmod{6p}$.  Also since $5$ and $1$ are relatively prime to $6$ and $p$ respectively, the solution will be relatively prime to $6p$.

Then by Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progression, the congruence class of the solution will contain (infinitely many) primes.

Comment: Awesome. I got as far as CRT myself, but Dirichlet's Theorem is just the missing piece I need. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!  That Dirichlet was quite the clever fellow :-)